# Listbox live sort using CollectionViewSource on ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, sorting, listbox

I would like to enable live sorting of ListBox items bound to an ObservableCollection; I would also like to enable the live sorting exclusively via my XAML markup (if possible).  As things stand, the list is properly sorted on application startup, but items are simply appended (not sorted) to the ListBox when new items are added to the ObservableCollection.

In my viewmodel I have the following public property:

```
public ObservableCollection<Equipment> EquipmentList { get; set; }
```

*Equipment* is an auto-generated class from Entity Framework which contains a public string property named 'Description'.  This is my sort target.

My XAML has the following DataTemplate which is intended to enable the live sorting:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="EquipmentDescriptionTemplate" 
                      DataType="{x:Type e:Equipment}">
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedEquipmentList" 
                              Source="{Binding Path=Description, 
                                  Mode=OneWay, 
                                  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                  IsLiveSortingRequested="True">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Description" 
                                     Direction="Ascending"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <CollectionViewSource.LiveSortingProperties>
                <clr:String>Description</clr:String>
            </CollectionViewSource.LiveSortingProperties>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </DataTemplate.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

And finally the XAML ListBox item:

```
<ListBox x:Name="EquipmentList" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=EquipmentList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" 
     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EquipmentDescriptionTemplate}" 
     IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
     SelectedItem="{Binding EquipmentSelection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
     Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
```

There's a lot of extra attributes which I added in my desperate attempts to get the live sorting to work (when in doubt, guess wildly!).  I've left them in so folks can see what I've tried, and snicker.

How do I enable live ListBox sorting via XAML?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll want to bind the ItemsSource to the CollectionViewSource, not to the underlying collection:

```
<ListBox x:Name="EquipmentList" 
         ItemsSource="{StaticResource SortedEquipmentList}" 
         ...
         />
```

Place the CollectionViewSource somewhere above, in your page's resource dictionary.  Bind its source to the underlying collection ("EquipmentList"):

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedEquipmentList" 
                      Source="{Binding EquipmentList.View}" 
                      IsLiveSortingRequested="True">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Description" Direction="Ascending"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    <CollectionViewSource.LiveSortingProperties>
        <clr:String>Description</clr:String>
    </CollectionViewSource.LiveSortingProperties>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

Comment: When I do this, I get the following design-time error: "An object of type CollectionViewSource cannot be applied to a property that expects type IEnumerable."  Is there something else I need to do to bind the ItemsSource to the CollectionViewSource item?

Comment: @StardewJellyfeather sorry, I think you just need `EquipmentList.View`.

Comment: I think I got it.  The ItemsSource needed some minor tweaking (I might have figured this out sooner but I'm a n00b): `ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedEquipmentList}}"`.  (On a side note, since you edited my original post, how did you do that?  I might save folks a lot of effort if I just do it right in the first place.  :)

Comment: @StardewJellyfeather how did I edit the post?  You should see an "edit" button underneath -- you can always edit your own posts, but if you're under a certain rep, then edits to other people's posts go through the review queue.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the XAML markup itself.  When I look at the side-by-side, mine was plain text whereas yours has all the proper colors.  I attempted to use the ` marker to specify code in the original post, but it didn't do the trick.

Comment: @StardewJellyfeather ah, right.  Don't use the marker for code -- indent 4 blocks.  Then make sure that the question is tagged with the language "C#", etc, and you should see the correct formatting.

Comment: If you leave out the LiveSortingProperties collection (but still set IsLiveSortingRequested to true) it will use the properties in the SortDescriptions by default.